# How to declare getter for a swift class field?

Tags: swift

I have below definition of a getter in a swift class. I want to check whether the value is nil, if yes create a new instance; otherwise return that value. I am now getting into recursive call since I call self.userHomeNvController inside the getter method. I wander how I should achieve this in swift.

```
var userHomeNavController:UINavigationController? {
    get {
        var ctr:UINavigationController? = self.userHomeNavController
        if self.userHomeNavController == nil{
            ctr = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserHomeNavigationController") as? UINavigationController
        }
        return ctr
    }

}
```

Comment: Have it as a stored property, and implement the check in `willGet`(observer) instead? Haven't tested this...

Comment: Do you mean replace get with willGet? I got an error on doing this. Also I searched but could not find the willGet method.

Comment: Oh, you're right. There's only `willSet` and `didSet`; my bad.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just doing this in your class's `init`?

Comment: I am not sure about the loading resources order. In class init, whether the storyboard is ready for use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lazy property initialized by running a closure:

```
    lazy var userHomeNavController: UINavigationController? = {
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserHomeNavigationController") as? UINavigationController
        return controller
    }()
```

Comment: I did work. But I don't understand why I need to add lazy for this property?

Comment: Your code does not initialize the property `userHomeNavController` until the first time it is accessed. That is exactly what `lazy` means in Swift.